# Двигать div с помощью мышки

Tags: javascript, html

```js
var div = document.getElementById('circle');
var listener = function(e) {
  div.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
  div.style.top = e.pageY + "px";
};

function move() {
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', listener);
}

function stop() {
  document.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener);
}
```

```css
.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1" id="circle" onMouseDown="move()" onKeyDown="stop()">
</div>
```

Comment: Рекомендую добавить описание возникшей проблемы

Comment: Да, проблема-то в чем? :)

Comment: там на самом деле вместо onKeyDown должно быть onMouseUp.У меня onMouseUp не срабатывает.

Comment: У вас проблема в том, что `onmouseup` вызывается не на круге, потому он и не ловит это событие. Сделайте так, чтобы круг был точно под курсором (например, так `e.pageX -50 + "px"; e.pageY -50 + "px"` - перенести в `listener`) и тогда `onmouseup` уже будет ловиться кругом

Answer (score 7):

Используйте [jquery draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/).

```js
$("#draggable").draggable();
```

```css
#draggable {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/overcast/jquery-ui.css" />
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content"></div>
```

Пример [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MAEvS/564/)

Answer (score 2):

1. Сделать позиционирование обьекта абсолютным
2. При событии нажатой кнопки брать позиционирование курсора и считать его до тех пор пока кнопку мыши не отожмете
3. Во время движения с зажатой кнопкой добавлять координаты курсора к элементу, который вы хотите переместить

Решение этой задачи очень подробно описанно тут, включая кроссбраузерные решения: [Drag&Drop](http://javascript.ru/ui/draganddrop)

Answer (score 1):

Предпочитаю навешивать события в JS, не затрагивая HTML. Вот перемещение с помощью мышки

```js
var div = document.getElementById('circle');
var listener = function(e) {
  div.style.left = e.pageX - 50 + "px";
  div.style.top = e.pageY - 50 + "px";
};

circle.addEventListener('mousedown', e => {
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', listener);
});

circle.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    document.removeEventListener('mousemove', listener);
});
```

```css
.block1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="block1" id="circle"></div>
```